# Why is this way of finding the angle between two points so inaccurate?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, angle

I'm trying to get one sprite to intersect with another using angles. This is the function I've used, found online:

```
def findAngle(x,y,x2,y2):
    deltaX = x2 - x
    deltaY = y2 - y

    return math.atan2(deltaY,deltaX)
```

However, this is horribly inaccurate. When the two sprites are at around the same X, they are still usually 100-200 pixels away from eachother.

Here is my entire program for you to run yourself.

```
import pygame
import math

screen_size = screen_width,screen_height = 700,500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

BLACK   = (   0,   0,   0)
WHITE   = ( 255, 255, 255)
RED     = ( 255,   0,   0)
GREEN   = (   0, 255,   0)
BLUE    = (   0,   0, 255)

class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)


class Particle(Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,size):
        self.image = pygame.Surface((size,size))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,size,size)

        self.angle = 0
        self.speed = 0

    def draw(self):

        self.rect.x -= math.cos(self.angle) * self.speed
        self.rect.y -= math.sin(self.angle) * self.speed
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, (self.rect.x,self.rect.y), self.rect.width)

def findAngle(x,y,x2,y2):
    deltaX = x2 - x
    deltaY = y2 - y

    return math.atan2(deltaY,deltaX)

class main:

    p1 = Particle(100,100,16)
    p2 = Particle(600,400,5)

    p2.angle = findAngle(100,100,600,400)
    p2.speed = 2

    done = False
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    done = True

                if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                        pass

        pygame.display.init()
        screen.fill(WHITE)

        p1.draw()
        p2.draw()

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.quit()
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "horribly inaccurate"? You do realise that the return value of `math.atan2()` is in radians, not degrees, right?

Comment: @GregHewgill I said in the question, it was usually 100-200 pixels above the target. I realize it's in radians. Run the program, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: It looks like you have your cos and sine reversed... what happens if you swap them?

Comment: For those of use who do not have `pygame` installed, could you explain?  The only time you call `findAngle`, you pass in constant arguments - `100, 100, 600, 400`.  What are you trying to achieve by doing that?

Comment: @Brionius Those constants are the coordinates of the two sprites. I was too lazy to type out the rect positions for each because this is just an example I wrote to demonstrate the problem. I'm trying to find the angle between the two sprites and have one move along that angle to intersect with the other. Right now, the sprite will pass by within 100-200 pixels of the other.

Comment: @Foon Exactly the same thing happens

Comment: @alexanderd5398 please show updated code from when you swapped cos and sin... as shown in my answer below, using simplified version of code, we get a much closer answer.

Comment: also, probably off topic... but shouldn't you call the Sprite base class contstructor from your Particle __init__

Answer (score 1):

You should use `cos` for the x-coordinate and `sin` for the y-coordinate. You have it backward in the `draw` function.

Comment: Exactly the same as before happens.

Answer (score 0):

P1 is at 100,100 and stationary
P2 is at 600,400 and moving at an angle of ~30 degrees (or more accurately, -120 degrees since you're doing -= instead of +=.
If you swap cos and sin,
 Every frame, p2 moves -1.715 units in the X direction and -1.02 units in the Y direction.  After it has moved 300 units in the Y (which would finish it), it should have moved 500 units in the X, which is what you're looking for.

Simplifying things to take pygame stuff:

```
import math

def findAngle(x,y,x2,y2):
    return math.atan2(y2-y,x2-x)

x = 600
y = 400
angle = findAngle(100,100,x,y)
dx = 2 * math.cos(angle)
dy = 2 * math.sin(angle)
while x > 100:
    x -= dx
    y -= dy
print "At end, we were at %f,%f"%(x,y)
```

This prints out: **At end, we were at 99.224131,99.534479**